# How to avoid memory problems when realizing a multiple PDF JAX-RS generation service?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jersey, jax-rs

My Jersey based JAX-RS 1.0 service generates multiple PDFs in the background per request which leads to a memory exception when this service is called in parallel by many clients. My idea was to queue the requests in some kind of batch which are then processed sequentially avoiding the memory exception. Looking for a solution I stumbled upon JMS, and Java EE 7's batch mechanism. Also log systems such as BookKeeper and Kafka seem to be candidates. But I'm wondering if there is a more lightweight solution? Is the event model from Java EE's DI standard suitable? Any experiences with a similar problem?